# not able to read configurations from appsettings.json in Blazor pre-rendering app

Tags: connection-string, blazor-webassembly, prerender, asp.net-blazor

[image: appsettings.json filw]

this is called in a class file that is present in the server project of the Blazor web assembly that is pre-rendering.

```
 public class DataAccessors
{
    private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

    public DataAccessors(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public DataAccessors()
    {
    }


    public MySqlConnection CSONLINE_MySqlConnection()
    {       
       string c =  Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings.localDevDb");
       string con =  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localDevDb"].ConnectionString; 
       var connectionstr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStrings.localDevDb"];
    }
  }
```

When the project is run, the variables c, con, connectionStr are all giving as null.

please see what I'm doing wrong or if it has anything to do with the pre-rendering of client, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```cs
Configuration.GetConnectionString("localDevDb");
```

Comment: nope, that didn't work either. While debugging, the Configuration object is also null